# Is there a CKeditor / Drupal module that allows for a one-button image upload (without requiring Flash)?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files, media

**Background:**
I'm looking to add an image upload button to CKeditor. Ideally, I'd like to automated the click responses to start IMCE and jump right to the IMCE Upload button. In fact, I'd like to put the IMCE upload button on CKeditor's tool bar.

**My Question:** 
Is there a way to put the IMCE Upload button directly onto the CKEditor tool bar just like we have here in side of StackExchange?

**What I've seen/tried:**
I've seen other methods recommending [One Click Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/ocupload) but this uses SWFloader. The [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module is great but people want a direct upload from inside the editor. They don't want to jump to another screen.

Answer (score 2):

The Insert module should be perfect for this https://www.drupal.org/project/insert

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.
>
> This module was previously known as FileField Insert.

Comment: Please also provide module descriptions when linking to Drupal modules.